# DocsList findFolder() issue

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is a google spreadsheet script question.

I have a GUI setup in order to search for "SouthWest" and then find a "test" sheet. This is the code I am using.

```
var file = DocsList.getFolder("SouthWest").find("test");
```

This works just fine when I run it under my account (as I have this folder and file setup correctly) but when another user is logged into google docs it will attempt to search for this folder/file under the new user instead of the owner of the document. Is there a way to have it just search the DocsList of the owner of the spreadsheet that is currently open? The error that I get under the new user is "Error encountered: Cannot find folder SouthWest." Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to access the same file, you can use the `getFileById` method and address it directly instead of searching every time:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_docslist#getFileById

Of course, you should make sure that all users are allowed to access that file.